# Acro package provides "! Missing number, treated as zero." after update to acro-v2.7b

Tags: texlive, xparse, acro, texlive-2017, xtemplate

I ran an update on texlive 2017 (via tlmgr) and I got an error for the acro package that I have not experienced before.

I have provided a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{RES}{
    short = RES ,
    long = Renewable Energy Sources ,
}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
    \ac{RES}
\end{document}
```

This is my output for \listfiles

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    acro.sty    2017/06/21 v2.7b Typeset Acronyms
   expl3.sty    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2017/07/19 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2017/07/19 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
xtemplate.sty    2017/07/19 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
zref-abspage.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2016/05/21 v2.26 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
translations.sty    2017/05/16 v1.6 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (C
N)
scrlfile.sty    2017/04/13 v3.23 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
 ***********
```

and this is the error in the log-file:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l__acro_RES_long-plural_set_bool 
l.7 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Could it be linked to the packages acro requires? They seem to be updated.

Comment: Somehow `\l__acro_RES_long-plural_set_bool` is undefined and tested using `\bool_if:NTF` which expects either a boolean equal to either `true` or `false` (I tweaked `\bool_if:NTF` a tiny bit and it used to detect arbitrary control sequences as `false`).  The acro code (or your use of it, I didn't check) was wrong all along and just worked by accident.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Do you mind reporting it here: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have created an issue: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/96/acro-package-provides-missing-number

Comment: @clemens : It looks as though the issue is related to the recent l3kernel update, which made `\bool_if:n(TF)` boolean expression evaluation greedy. I also cannot use `acro` currently, same error here. Most l3 based pkg need a fix (e. g. `media9` fixed yesterday).

Comment: Is there a workaround? How can I downgrade?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in v2.7c (2017/08/28) which is on its way to CTAN and should be available soon in the major distributions.