# Weird error “Missing number treated as zero” Acro Package

Tags: acro

I am writing my PhD Dissertation. I am using tex studio. There was some problem in my windows and I had to reinstall my windows and as a results I reinstalled. However, I am receiving following error with respect to the acro package while recompiling the file.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \l__acro_abs_long-plural_set_bool 
l.2 ...securities, list = Asset-Backed Securities}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

The complete MWE is given below:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
   \usepackage[tc]{titlepic}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{newtxtext}
   \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{tocbibind}
   \usepackage{amsthm}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{mathptmx}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \DeclareMathOperator*{\Soperator}{\mathit{S}}
   \usepackage{calrsfs}
   \usepackage{imakeidx}
   \makeindex[options=-s index, columns=2]
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{url}
   \usepackage[natbibapa,indexpackage]{apacite}
   \bibliographystyle{apacitex}
   \usepackage[final]{graphicx}
   \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
   %page margins
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \usepackage{textcomp}
   \usepackage{textgreek}
   \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
   %line spacing
   \usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
   \captionsetup[table]{font=small,skip=6pt}
   \captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=8pt}
   \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small,skip=-24pt}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{tabulary}
   \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
   \usepackage{array,longtable,tabularx}
   \usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e,ltxtable,pdflscape,filecontents}
   \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
   \usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
   \usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
   \usepackage[flushleft, online]{threeparttablex}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{pdflscape}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
   \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
   \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    citecolor = black,      
    urlcolor=blue,
   }
   \urlstyle{same}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{eurosym}
   \usepackage{quoting}
   \usepackage{csquotes} 
   \newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
   \def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}
   \usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
   \usepackage{acro}
   \acsetup{list-style=longtable}
   \input{acronym}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \preto\chapter\acresetall
 \begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\title{\bfseries {{\LARGE Thesis Title}}\\[16cm]}
\author{\sc{\LARGE \textbf{Ahmed Arif}}}

\date{}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{center}
  \large This is a PhD Thesis.  
    \vspace{3cm} \\

    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{EDLE.jpg}

    \vspace{9cm}
    \large A collaboration between \\
    \vspace{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logos.jpg}
    \end{center}
    \frontmatter \thispagestyle{empty}
     \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
    \printacronyms[name= List of Acronyms,sort=true,heading=chapter]

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Chapter 1: Introduction}
    This is introduction chapter about \ac{abs}.
    \bibliography{library}
    \include{./Chapters/Appendices}
    \printindex
    \end{document}
```

I am using a separate input file for the acronym. All the entries in acronym file are made like this.

```
    \DeclareAcronym{abs}{short =ABS, long = asset-backed securities, list = Asset-Backed Securities}
```

This file used to compile perfectly, but after reinstalling the above error is appearing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a *Minimal* Working Example.  Which of those packages can you take out and still have the error occur?

Comment: @Teepeemm - it is a maximal non-working example.

Comment: I think this is the same issue like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383018/acro-package-provides-missing-number-treated-as-zero-after-update

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/96/acro-package-provides-missing-number#comment-38818522